# After a Pokemon hatches from an egg will it show a shiny model, or will it look the same as a non-shiny Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm currently batch breeding in hopes of a shiny, but I was curious if the model of the hatched Pokemon shows whether or not the Pokemon is shiny.

So based on the model will I be able to tell if the Pokemon shiny, or will I have to check within menus to see?

Reference image ([borrowed from here](http://www.nintendolife.com/forums/online_gaming/pokemon_x_and_y_friend_code_exchange?start=85160)):
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will look shiny immediately if it is shiny. You will not see the sparkles though as far as I can tell. I only hatched one shiny myself. For pokemon that may be very similar you should probably also check for the marker in the pokedex unless you know what to look for.

This video for example shows a shiny Honedge hatching. It's animation was otherwise the same as usual.

Comment: Will it show the sparkles? Some shiny forms don't look that different from regular colored forms (Pichu, for instance).